# Get the Dataproc cluster name from within the PySpark code

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

From within a pyspark code running on a dataproc cluster, is it possible to get the dataproc cluster name where it is running?

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc cluster name is available as VM metadata `attributes/dataproc-cluster-name`. You can get it through

1. CLI

```
/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-cluster-name
```

2. HTTP

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" \
"http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/dataproc-cluster-name"
```

For regular clusters (non personal-auth), you can also infer the cluster name from the VM host name, just remove the part after `-m` or `-w`.